# so simple, yet so hard

Tags: python

> Write a function id_formater(fn, ln, appelation, city, year) that returns a string of the form "appelation. ln, fn (city, year)"

Here's what I did:

```
def id_formater(fn, ln, appelation, city, year):
    return(appelation, ln, fn, (city, year))
id_formater("Albert","Einstein", "Dr", "Bern", 1879)
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `return("a", "b")` why would this work? What syntax construct do you have here? It looks like you are trying to let python guess what you want to do

Comment: @DownloadPizza Write a function id_formater(fn, ln, appelation, city, year) that returns a string of the form "appelation. ln, fn (city, year)"

Comment: You are returning a tuple, not a string. The only syntax error here is specific to the interactive interpreter, where a blank line needs to be entered after the function definition to terminate it before you can call it.

Comment: Learn about string concatenation and casting. It is a simple task

Comment: One purpose of SO is to serve as a repository of knowledge to help not just the person asking for help, but people that may have similar issues in the future. That's one reason why it's important to write a title that summarizes your problem. Otherwise, only you can get advantage of the answer. Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [f-string](https://python-tutorials.in/python-f-strings/):

```
def id_formater(fn, ln, appelation, city, year):
    return f"{appelation}. {ln}, {fn} ({city}, {year})"
id = id_formater("Albert","Einstein", "Dr", "Bern", 1879)
print(id)
```

Output:

```
Dr. Einstein, Albert (Bern, 1879)
```